# MS Teams Calling - Cannot read .wav file

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

When a call has been established, attempting to play a prompt using any .wav file results in the following error 500:
"message": "Did not get valid FileSource from downloaded file content"
Tried a few different .wav's:
https://myaudio.blob.core.windows.net/prompts/couchplayin.wav
https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/interface_sound_effects/sound107.wav

Code:

```
`var url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/calls/' + callID + 
"/playPrompt";
           axios.post(url,
               {
                 "clientContext": "d45324c1-fcb5-430a-902c-f20af696537c",
                 "prompts": [
                   {
                     "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mediaPrompt",
                     "mediaInfo": {
                       "uri": "https://myaudio.blob.core.windows.net/prompts/couchplayin.wav",
                       "resourceId": "1D6DE2D4-CD51-4309-8DAA-70768651088E"
                     },
                     "loop": 5
                   }
                 ]
               },        
             {
               headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
             }).then(response => { 
              console.log(response)
           })
           .catch(error => {
               console.log(error.response)
           });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same issue, I setup a custom WAV file in itunes and converted it using the following parameters and it was successful.

16-bits per sample
16000 sampling rate
mono/single channel.